# columnwidthchanging event of Listview is not fire?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, column-width

I try not to allow resize column in listview but I can't
I don't know reason why columnwidthchanging event of listview is not fire
I try debug and see never into method  listView1_ColumnWidthChanging

In Form1.Designer.cs:

```
    partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.listView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
        this.columnHeader1 = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
        this.columnHeader2 = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // listView1
        // 
        this.listView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
        this.columnHeader1,
        this.columnHeader2});
        this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 103);
        this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
        this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(259, 97);
        this.listView1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        this.listView1.ColumnWidthChanging += new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnWidthChangingEventHandler(this.listView1_ColumnWidthChanging);
        // 
        // columnHeader1
        // 
        this.columnHeader1.Text = "ID";
        this.columnHeader1.Width = 0;
        // 
        // columnHeader2
        // 
        this.columnHeader2.Width = 200;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.listView1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.ListView listView1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader columnHeader1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader columnHeader2;
}
```

In Form1.cs:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void listView1_ColumnWidthChanging(object sender, ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            e.NewWidth = 0x0;
        }
    }
```

PLEASE, HELP ME!!!!!! T_T

Comment: Works fine for me post the full code which reproduces the issue

Comment: Thhis is full my code.It's simple but event is not fire

Comment: This can't be the full snippet, what I'm asking is a code to copy paste and run to see the problem

Comment: Did you attach this event to the control?  Such as through the form designer, or by something such as `listView1.ColumnWidthChanging += listView1_ColumnWidthChanging`?  The _presence_ of the event does nothing if it isn't added as a handler to the control.

Comment: code to copy paste and run to see the problem.it's empty.It's nothing.when I debug, breakpoint never enter into method listView1_ColumnWidthChanging

Comment: @DonBoitnott : yes, man.I updated my code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using a 'hidden' first column to piggy-back a value.  This is exactly what "Tag" property is used for.

```
var listViewItem = listView1.Items.Add(rowData);
listViewItem.Tag = id;
```

You can then retrieve this later:

```
var selectedListViewItem = listView1.Items.SelectedItems[0];
var selectedID = (int)selectedListViewItem.Tag;
```

There are settings in Windows which can affect the firing of ColumnWidthChanging event - and ways to work around it.  But I would recommend not going there if you do not have to.